# In app purchase not working when moderator review my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

I am working on IAP first time. I have created test user and working good in sandbox env. I can see my Purchase and buy it as well(And of course i added StoreKit framework.), but problem is that: when i upload update with IAP to AppStore - moderator has reject my app, here is a reason:

We found that while you have submitted In App Purchase products for your app, the In App Purchase functionality is not present in your binary. Please see the attached screenshot/s for more information.(there is no some Purchase on the screen, empty space instead)

If you would like to utilize In App Purchase in your app, you will need to upload a new binary that incorporates the In App Purchase API to enable users to make a purchase

I just don't understand how it's possible? Why when i testing IAP - it's works fine, but it doesn't work when moderator doing it? All IAP have "Cleared for Sale" and "Waiting for review" status

Now if i upload app to the store will IAP works? Or maybe i need to do some additional action before?

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _iapArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    iap1 = @"com.mypurchase.addcoins1";

    [self paymentCheck];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];
}

- (void)paymentCheck{

    if([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]){
        NSLog(@"User can make payments");

        SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObjects:iap1, nil]];
        productsRequest.delegate = self;
        [productsRequest start];

    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"User cannot make payments due to parental controls");
        //this is called the user cannot make payments, most likely due to parental controls
    }
}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response{
    SKProduct *validProduct = nil;
    int count = [response.products count];
    if(count > 0){

        _iapArray = response.products;
        indicator.hidden = YES;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
    else if(!validProduct){
        NSLog(@"No products available");

        UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                              message:@"Error"
                                                             delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [myAlertView show];
        //this is called if your product id is not valid, this shouldn't be called unless that happens.
    }
}


- (IBAction)purchase:(SKProduct *)product{
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions{
    for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions){
        switch (transaction.transactionState){
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing: NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Purchasing");
                //called when the user is in the process of purchasing, do not add any of your own code here.
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                //this is called when the user has successfully purchased the package (Cha-Ching!)
                // [self doRemoveAds]; //you can add your code for what you want to happen when the user buys the purchase here, for this tutorial we use removing ads
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Purchased - %@", transaction.payment.productIdentifier);

                if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:iap1]) {
                    [self addCoins:5];
                }

                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Restored");
                //add the same code as you did from SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased here
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                //called when the transaction does not finnish
                if(transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled){
                    NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Cancelled");
                    //the user cancelled the payment ;(
                }
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect that the reviewer doesn't know how to make a purchase in your app. Is the in-app purchase screenshot showing clearly how to access your store? Is it clear how to make a purchase in your app?

Comment: Check the status of in app purchase in your itunes connect? Is it in ready for sale state? Check out the product id for it.

Comment: No, they know how to make a purchase in my app, but when they opening view with IAP - they do not appear, just error - i guess - (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse method return not valid product :( IAP had "waiting for review" status when i uploaded my build to review - is it right?

Comment: Have you simultaneously submitted your IAP products for review as well (as in, they were attached to the submit version)? This is a step that's not necessarily obvious the first time and can lead to "no valid products" in review but everything working correctly in sandbox. If you don't know what I'm referring to, once you make your IAP entries, you have to go to the In-App Purchase section of the _app_ in iTC to make the connection.

Answer (score 0):

As per their reply, you have integrated IAP in application but you have not used it. So, can you please make sure you have properly integrated IAP in application ? Please test in same Device and iOS if they mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I updated my question (added my code which implement IAP), it's enough for make IAP? Or what else API i need to add? I already added StoreKit.framework and write a code, which implemented IAP, and it works fine on my device with demo account, maybe i missed something?